# "Expected: }" when defining hash using {key: value} notation

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

IntelliJ with the RubyMine plug-in is giving me an error for the following code:

```
get '/agent' do
    mustache :agent, :locals => {agent: request.user_agent}
end
```

The error is ocurring on the second line, at the colon following the word agent, and it states:

> Expected: }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ agent: request.user_agent }` is a new syntax for hashes. You need Ruby 1.9 or newer to use that syntax.

It seems like you are still using Ruby 1.8, If so then write `{ :agent => request.user_agent }` instead.

Or your version of IntelliJ does not understand this new syntax. Then you might want to investigate if there is a newer version of IntelliJ available.

Comment: That makes good sense, although I know my version of Ruby is 1.9.3. IntelliJ must not be recognizing the new syntax

Comment: Yea, seems to be a problem with IntelliJ: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/457333